# iOS 13 Voice Control UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios13, uiaccessibility, voice-control

The iOS13 **Voice Control** feature has a command 'Scroll Down'. This command works for UITableViews but does not seem to work for UIScrollViews with scrollable content.

1. Is this intended?
2. Intended or not, is there a way to enable this command to work on a UIScrollView?

Example: a UILabel with a lot of text inside a UIScrollView (constraints are correct - it scrolls and is acknowledged by ***Voice Over*** saying 'Page 1 of 3' when active)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> This command works for UITableViews but does not seem to work for UIScrollViews with scrollable content.

... only if this content is a huge UILabel content that must be scrollable: add many other elements *(sliders, buttons...)* and you'll notice that scrolling is enabled.

About that, in the [TextKit Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/221/) *(2018 WWDC video)*, it's highly recommended to **use a UITextView** for this purpose:
[image]

> Is there a way to enable this command to work on a UIScrollView?

**Switch the label and your scroll view for a text view instead** to make the Voice Control feature work with your specific use case.

Otherwise, it works with many other elements different from UILabel: the scroll view knows its content size and when it has to scroll down/up but the Voice Control feature doesn't recognize the label content as an element to directly interact with inside a scroll view.

I tested with a button and a huge UILabel as you did:
[image]

1. `Scroll down` that worked to reach the end of my label.
2. `Scroll up` that never works.

The label seems to be a kind of empty box that Voice Control ignores in a scroll view: to enable this command in a scroll view, just **replace your label by a text view**.
Now, if your use case is a single UILabel in a UIScrollView, remove them to **display a UITextView** instead.

**EDIT**
Here's the Xcode screenshot to make the `UITextView` scrolling work with the VoiceControl feature:
[image]

... with the results hereunder:
[image]

As you can notice, this is just a blank project with a simple text view: iOS recognizes this single element and acts as desired when `Scroll down` and `Scroll up` are vocalized.

Comment: If I replace the ScrollView + UILabel with a UITextView it still doesn't scroll with the Voice Control though. Did you manage to get that to work? Right now I just have a blank ViewController with a UITextView constrained to top/bottom/left/right of the View.

Great thought on the label just being a kind of empty element in the scrollview too!

Comment: @Wych: it works well as the added screenshots highlight. Just create a blank project and add your text view with your constraints and personal content.

Comment: @xle-22 ah yep I can reproduce your functionality from a blank UITextView, but if you make it not Editable the voiceover stops working as intended. Seems it acts the same as a UILabel in a ScrollView in this regard?